# Laravel Lumen authentication events

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Does Lumen authentication events works as well as Laravel works?

I have registered Login event but the event does not get dispatch when a user login

```
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
  
    "Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login"=>[
        MyListener::class
    ]
];
```

**update**

im using `tymon/jwt-auth` for my login

```
private function GenerateResponse(){
    if (!$this->status){
       return response()->json([
          'status'=>Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY ,
           'errors'=>[
               'code'=>[
                   "invalid code"
               ]
           ]
       ],Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY );
    }
   $token= auth()->login($this->user);
    return (new UserResource($this->user,$token))->response()->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

Comment: Documentation says events work same as Laravel. https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/8.x/events

Comment: If your event's aren't dispatching you need to check how your authentication works (or share your code on how you authenticate users)

Comment: i updated my question and and login logic note that im using tymon/jwt-auth pakcage this package does not fire login event.

Comment: Slightly offtopic: have you checked what `tymon/jwt-auth` actually does under the hood? It is not a stateless authentication mechanism. It is simply a glorified cookie that retrieves a user object from an ID using a query, just like the regular Laravel authentication does. Why are you using it? A lot of people are using this package so they have `JWT`, that is theoretically true but a cookie will often suffice and is much simpler to work with.

Comment: @Flame no i have not checked what does this package do under the hood.
i needed ```JWT``` authentication  for my application which my client side is an android application. and i believe it is stateless and is not using session https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/392

Comment: My bad I phrased that wrongly; the mechanism is indeed stateless, but the retrieval of the user object is not (in the default implementation that is, the JWT does a db query for the user ID it contains, on each request. But since you are talking about an Android app I assume you changed this since you are not directly connected to a database). To make utmost use of a stateless mechanism, you'd want to save the user object (JSON stringified) in the JWT so it does not need to be retrieved again on each request (and also the permissions of the user for instance).